# Cannot install or move Android Apps to SD Card - is it a flaw from the Android or from the phone manufacturer?

Tags: sd-card

From my understanding, while the Galaxy S4 does offer a memory card slot, it's worth mentioning that you can't install apps on the memory card and can only use it for storing movies, music, pictures, etc.

So, is this a problem with the Android 4 OS not capable of allowing phone user to install or move apps to the SD card?

or

is it that the phone manufacturer are not capable of producing a phone that allow user to use the SD card slot given that the limited space for a 16 GB Samsung Galaxy S4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android supports moving apps to the SD card since version 2.2 (only for apps which allow it); however, this feature can be disabled when building the ROM. Apparently Samsung decided that about 9 GB of user-accessible internal memory should be enough for apps, and disabled the “move to SD” function in their stock ROMs for the 16 GB Galaxy S4 model.

However, there are [recent news](http://www.theverge.com/2013/6/6/4401652/samsung-galaxy-s4-update-storage-improvements-sd-card-apps) that Samsung heard complaints of 16 GB Galaxy S4 users and enabled the “move to SD” function in a software update.

Comment: Exactly. The same applies to the *LG Optimus 4X*, by the way. And in the support forum the techs claim it's Android's fault ("Android 4.x doesn't support this") -- which is absolutely *not* true and confuses users. So right: Android supports this starting with Froyo (2.2), and did not stop supporting this feature. If it's not available, you either have no SDCard, or the manufacturer diesabled that feature.